# Starcraft 2 scoring: Why am I ranked last in this game

Tags: starcraft-2

[image: screenshot:]

I'm the last player in this game. How did it calculate the ranking? So we lost the game and I didn't kill any buildings but how am I ranked even lower than the other guys in my team? Is it purely based on the 4 presented numbers or there are other invisible factors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look closer at your screenshot, "Structures Razed Count" is highlighted. It is sorted by that category. You are technically tied for last with TheBakery. If you clicked on the other headings it would sort by that in descending order from highest to lowest.

Comment: I see, thanks. I thought there were some more complicated algorithms. So it's just a straight up numerical sort.